# IPython !! not working

Tags: python, macos, ipython

So I've starting using IPython on my Mac. The !! operator, which is supposed to execute a shell command and get the output as useful data, is generating syntax errors. It appears to be just interpreting it as (! (!ls)), and spitting out !ls: command not found. I can't google exclamation marks and I didn't know where else to turn

Comment: you're conflating features of the execution shell (`sh`, `bash`, etc) with python's REPL.  Can you break down the problem with more specifics?  How is this related to python?

Comment: @BrianCain That's a feature of IPython (note the leading `I`). An enhanced REPL that allows for shell commands.

Comment: @Keith, ok, I'm on board now.  But I still think that `!!` isn't what OP wants.  It's probably just `!`, right?

Comment: @BrianCain IPython does have a `!!` command, that converts the shell output to some Python value. On my Linux system it works fine (I get a list of name with `In [1]: !!ls`). But I don't have a Mac to test it on so I can't help with this question. Or it may be a new feature and his version is older.

Comment: Ok, so [here's a reference](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.osm.html#IPython.core.magics.osm.OSMagics.bang) and I'm guessing OP should check their shell's `PATH` to make sure it's set correctly.

Comment: What version of Ipython is it?

Comment: Turns out I was wrong the whole time. I had though that !! would allow you to embed shell commands in Python expressions (for instance: `for object in (!!ls):`. Turns out I was wrong and there's no way to get around using that temporary variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you probably only want a single exclamation mark [[docs]](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#manual-capture-of-command-output), at least if you want to do anything with the output.  For example:

```
localhost-2:tmp $ ipython
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.12 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: !ls
a.txt

In [2]: z = !ls

In [3]: z
Out[3]: ['a.txt']

In [4]: !!ls
Out[4]: ['a.txt']
```

but (which is what I'm assuming you're seeing)

```
In [10]: z = !!ls

In [11]: z
Out[11]: ['/bin/sh: !ls: command not found']
```

You can type `%sx?` for more information about what `!!ls` actually does.

Comment: I'm trying to do double, as per the documentation here: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13/interactive/reference.html#system-shell-access. Single works just fine, but I can't embed it in expressions (ie `for item in !!ls`)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the documentation doesn't contain any examples that suggest that's supported.  You can use `!` or `!!` at the start of a line; you can write `name = !somecmdhere`; AFAIK, that's about it.

Comment: Rereading it, it looks like you're right. Alright then never mind. I could have sworn I saw it somewhere...

Comment: Yep, you can't embed it in arbitrary expressions. The reason is, there are regexes that spot `!cmd` and `foo = !cmd`, but regexes are not powerful enough to parse Python code, so we can't find it anywhere you might want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The `!!` shortcut is an alias for the `%sx ls` magic command. This was introduced [recently](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/commit/9e599d125d78fc6f199c0add93c1a09c09bdc2bc) so your version may not have that functionality.

Comment: %sx and !! both work from the beginning of the line, and %sx works with variable assignment. The problem is that neither of them work for embedding expressions